# How to use Charindex for one or the other character

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, charindex

I have a string with a bunch of numbers but it contains one letter somewhere in the center of the string. This letter can either be 'A' or 'B'. I am trying to find out the position of this letter with the Charindex() function. However it doesn't work when you have two search parameters:

```
select  charindex('[A,B]','190118A3700000')
```

I tried it out with a range and wildcards but it did not work. So what I want are these two separate queries combined in one:

```
select  charindex('A','190118A3700000')
select  charindex('B','190118A3700000')
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `patindex()`:

```
select patindex('%[A,B]%', '190118A3700000')
```

Or, if you want the first non-digit:

```
select patindex('%[^0-9]%', '190118A3700000')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0c6069a74be9c97e09045b6479ee1ff) is a db<>fiddle.

`charindex()` does not understand wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

If `charindex` doesn't find that character, it returns 0 so all you need to do is

```
select col, charindex('A', col) + charindex('B', col) as position
from your_table;
```

Another alternative

```
select col, charindex('A', replace(col, 'B', 'A')) as position
from your_table;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12eb14c07ab0cda45c438fd3afa73ff4)

Comment: I immediately thought of PATINDEX and never would have considered this approach. Not something I have seen before. Cool.