# how to filter out the year using mask characters or any other trick in the string below?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace, patindex

I have this function to clear off the unwanted characters:

```
USE MASTER
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH ENCRYPTION, SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'

    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')

    RETURN @String

END
```

I use that function in the following script that I working on to get the last time the machine has been rebooted:

I also [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2455750/1501497), I don't want [repeating spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2182877/1501497) in the returned string.

```
--=================================
-- script to get last time the machine rebooted
-- and what sql server and host OS do we have?
-- Marcello Miorelli 16-mar-2020
--=================================
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#RADHE') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #RADHE

    --create the table
    CREATE TABLE #Radhe (logdate datetime not null default (getdate()), 
                         processinfo varchar(108) not null default ('Radhe'),
                         the_text varchar(4000))


    -- create a non-unique clustered index
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IXC_RADHE_RADHE ON #RADHE(logdate desc, processinfo  asc)


    -- load the table
    INSERT #Radhe 
exec sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'Copyright (c)'

SELECT @@SERVERNAME as [Server Name]
      ,R.logdate AS [Last Time Server Rebooted]
      ,REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                               REPLACE(
                                master.dbo.fn_StripCharacters(R.the_text, 
                               '^a-z0-9()#@.<>^:^-^ '),
                               'Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation','')
                               ,' ','<>')
                       ,'><','')
              ,'<>',' ')

FROM #RADHE R
```

this on my current machine gives me:

[image]

and that is fine. However, when I go to check some other machine built in 2017 instead of 2019
then I get the following:

[image]

**Question:**

I want to get rid of the following piece of script, independent of the year (2019):

`Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation`

What [mask characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/712589/1501497) can I use on this situation?

Maybe I can achieve that with [patindex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60120479/1501497)?
I have tried:

[How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012802/1501497)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PATINDEX` to find where in the string the pattern `Copyright (C) [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Microsoft Corporation` starts and then `STUFF` to remove the 40 characters after that start point.

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64)    Sep 13 2019 15:49:57    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation   Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: )'


SELECT STUFF(@text,PATINDEX('%Copyright (C) [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Microsoft Corporation%',@text),40,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used `PATINDEX` to remove the 40 characters as [suggested by Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714503/1501497)
and it is working like a charm now:

```
--=================================
-- script to get last time the machine rebooted
-- and what sql server and host OS do we have?
-- Marcello Miorelli 16-mar-2020
--=================================
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#RADHE') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #RADHE

    --create the table
    CREATE TABLE #Radhe (logdate datetime not null default (getdate()), 
                         processinfo varchar(108) not null default ('Radhe'),
                         the_text varchar(4000))


    -- create a non-unique clustered index
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX 
    IXC_RADHE_RADHE ON #RADHE(logdate desc, processinfo  asc)


    -- load the table
    INSERT #Radhe 
exec sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'Copyright (c)'

UPDATE #RADHE
SET the_text = master.dbo.fn_StripCharacters(the_text,'^a-z0-9()#@.<>^:^-^ ')

--select * from #radhe

 SELECT @@SERVERNAME as [Server Name]
       ,R.logdate AS [Last Time Server Rebooted]
       ,REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                 R.the_text,
                                SUBSTRING ( R.the_text,PATINDEX(
                                   '%Copyright (C)%',R.the_text),40),'')
                                ,' ','<>')
                        ,'><','')
               ,'<>',' ')

 FROM #RADHE R
```

server built in 2017:

[image]

and this one 2019:

[image]